# C# SOAP Client adds large amount of time

Tags: c#, soap

I'm trying to call our instance of the NetSuite API.  This requires generating a nonce and timestamp along with consumer and token keys.  When doing all that and sending the request from Postman, it takes about 6 seconds.  When generating a basic C# project, adding the SOAP Endpoint as a "Connected Service", and calling it, it takes 20 seconds.  Why is it taking so long to send the request through C#?

```
var credentials = new TokenCredentials(accountId, consumerKey, consumerSecret, tokenId, tokenSecret);
var client = new ServiceReference1.NetSuitePortTypeClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(<url>), client.Endpoint.Address.Identity, client.Endpoint.Address.Headers.ToArray());
var passport = credentials.GeneratePassport();
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var something = await client.getAsync(null, passport, null, null, null, new RecordRef {type = RecordType.customer, typeSpecified = true, internalId = "2116"});
sw.Stop();
var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `async` with `await` instead of the `Result` property?

Comment: @BiesiGrr The code that prompted this question has await in it.  Here I use `.Result` just because it's in a synchronous context so I can't await it.